# Do software systems realy have more states than hardware ones?

Tags: theory

In *[No Silver Bullet](http://faculty.salisbury.edu/~xswang/Research/Papers/SERelated/no-silver-bullet.pdf)*, Fred Brooks claims that "Software systems have orders of magnitudes more states than computers do", which makes them harder to design and test (and chips are already pretty hard to test!).

This is counter-intuitive to me: any running software system can be mapped to a computer in a certain state, and it seems like a computer could be in a state that doesn't represent a running software system. Thus, a computer should have many more potential states than a software system.

Does Brooks intend some particular meaning that I'm missing? Or does a computer really have fewer potential states than the software systems it can run?

Comment: turing machine....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's first think about Turing machines.

A Turing machine consists of an unbounded tape which contains symbols, a head and a small control unit which is a *finite* state automata that controls how the machine reads, moves and modifies the symbols on the tape.

**Fact:** there exist [universal Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine), i.e. machines that read from the tape the description of an other Turing machine and execute it on some given input. In other words: even with just a finite number of states in the control unit such machines can simulate *every* possible other Turing machine.

Reading the description of a Turing machine is the same as reading a software program stored in memory.

In this sense **if** you count as the number of states of the hardware the number of states in the control unit, and if software is the description of a Turing machine written on the tape, then *yes* a finite hardware can simulate infinite softwares, yet the softwares surely contains Turing machines with more states than the one simulating it.

If you however consider as state the whole *state of the computation*, i.e. including the state of the tape, then you are right: every simulation corresponds to specific possible states in this sense and there are many states that are not valid, or are unreachable.

In the same way modern computers consists of a set of hardware that implements this control unit, and then memory which is our tape. If you do *not* consider the state of the memory as part of the state of the hardware, the same applies: a finite computer, given enough memory, could execute every possible program on every possible input, yet its controlling parts are only finite.

---

This said I wouldn't take such assertions too literally or too seriously...
The point is simply: software systems's number of states grows extremely rapidly.